# 'Player' has no attribute 'draw'

Tags: python, class, oop, pygame

Trying to make my own game in pygame, and I have encountered an error, that I just cant seem to get around. I incorporated a class into the program, called Player. This class is supposed to hold information regarding the player, (image, input, etc). However when I try to call the class and draw it onto the screen. I get the error, ''Player has no attribute 'draw'''. Without using a class I can just blit it onto the screen, now something is different.

```
import pygame
from sys import exit


pygame.init()

#player info
x = 450
y = 840
vel = 5

#window info
screen_w = 800
screen_h = 600

# player movement etc

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        player_surf = pygame.image.load('game graphics/player_stand.png').convert_alpha()
        #scaled player image
        player_surf = pygame.transform.scale(player_surf,(500,500))
        
        self.player_rect = player_surf.get_rect(midbottom = (x,y))
        
    def player_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()    
        if keys[pygame.K_d] and self.rect.bottomright <= screen_h or self.rect.bottomleft >=screen_w:
            x += vel
        elif keys[pygame.K_a] and self.rect.bottomright <= screen_h or self.rect.bottomleft >=screen_w:
            x -= vel
            
    def update(self):
        self.player_input()
        
# def draw(self):
#     pass
#window stuff

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_w,screen_h))
pygame.display.set_caption('Cave In')

#clock

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#background

cave_surf = pygame.image.load('game graphics/background.png').convert()
cave_surf = pygame.transform.scale(cave_surf, (screen_w,screen_h)).convert()


#game

while True:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(cave_surf,(0,0))
    
    #here is the problem :/

    Player.draw(screen)
    Player.update()
    pygame.display.update()
```

My question is, using the Player class, how do I get it to appear on the screen?

Thanks.

EDIT ---------------------->

After watching youtube videos, looking a other programs, and experimenting. I still can not get the character on screen. I have updated my code, and I now have a different error message at the moment. Here is the updated program.

```
import pygame, random
from sys import exit
pygame.init()

#player info
x = 450
y = 840
vel = 5
health = 5

#window info
screen_w = 800
screen_h = 600

# player movement etc

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.player_surf = pygame.image.load('game graphics/player_stand.png').convert_alpha()
    #scaled player image
    self.player_surf = pygame.transform.scale(self.player_surf,(500,500))
    self.rect = self.player_surf.get_rect(midbottom = (x,y))
    self.x_speed = vel
    self.health = health
    self.direction = 1 #1 = right 0 = left
    
def player_input(self):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()    
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        x += vel
    elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= vel
        
def update(self):
    self.player_input()

# drawing the player on screen?
    def draw_hero(self,screen,hero):
        current_hero_sprite = 
pygame.transform.flip(current_hero_sprite, True, False)
        screen.blit(current_hero_sprite,hero.rect)
    
        pygame.display.update(screen)

#window stuff

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_w,screen_h))
pygame.display.set_caption('Cave In')
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('game 
graphics/player_stand.png'))

#clock

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#background

cave_surf = pygame.image.load('game 
graphics/background.png').convert()
cave_surf = pygame.transform.scale(cave_surf, 
(screen_w,screen_h)).convert()


#game loop

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(cave_surf,(0,0))


    screen.blit(Player)
    Player.update()
    pygame.display.update()
```

My current error message is, ''line 75 TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not type'' There is similar problems on the on stack overflow/Quora etc. However none seem to really solve the problem?

Probably just a noob mistake.

Comment: which line is line 75 here ?

Comment: Found a fix, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED -->

```
screen.blit(player.player_surf,player.rect)
```

Thats it...

Answer (score 0):

A class is a template to create (instantiate) an object. First instantiate a new Player object, then you can call methods on it.

```
# At the beginning, instantiate the player object as defined in the class.
player = Player()

#...

player.draw(screen)
player.update()
```

Comment: @theHouseExpands This is a good sign, that's something else that is missing to initialize the configuration. I'd suggest google the error message, it gives results. (or check tutorials on pygame)

Comment: can i bounty this question?

Comment: What was the next error message that you got again ? Apparently the last comment has been deleted.

Comment: Hey @Pac0, thank you for all your help. I updated the question above using the changes I made to the program. I am not getting the same error, (maybe im doing something right?)